# Stripe.net and Stripe API

Tags: api, stripe.net

Im looking to find out the latest stripe.net (https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/tree/v6.11.0) compatibility with stripe.com api (https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades).

Does anybody know if there is a compatibility relationship between the stripe.net and stripe.com api?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#versioning):

> When we make backwards-incompatible changes to the API, we release new, dated versions.  The current version is 2016-07-06. Read our [API upgrades guide](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades) to see our [API changelog](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#api-changelog) and to learn more about backwards compatibility.
>
> ...
>
> All requests will use your account API settings, unless you override the API version.
>
> ...
>
> To set the API version on a specific request, send a `Stripe-Version` header.

Stripe.net sets the `Stripe-Version` for every request -- currently to `2016-07-06`.  In the GitHub repo, you can see the code that sets it.  See [here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/5b4084af0f434af971575cf9c1602975930621a5/src/Stripe.net/Infrastructure/Public/StripeConfiguration.cs#L12) for the API Version it uses and [here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/96cdbaffa5609ab6f8c4925342247c5a8be6f0ac/src/Stripe.net/Infrastructure/Requestor.cs#L148) where it actually adds the header.